# no columns in mysqlite database

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I made an **android eclipse** project that uses **SQLite** as a database.

Some *errors* occur when I try to run the project on the phone. When I click the view button(to view my database), The application says:
no columns in my database.

Why does it happen?

*Data Layer:*

```
public class Translator {

public static final String KEY_ROWID ="_id";
public static final String KEY_DESC ="page_desc";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME  ="Translatordb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE ="pageTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION  = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

public static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    
    public DbHelper(Context context) {  
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        KEY_ROWID + " STRING PRIMARY KEY, " +
        KEY_DESC + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                );
    }


    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    
}

 public Translator(Context c){
     ourContext = c;
}

public Translator open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String id, String description){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_ROWID,id);
    cv.put(KEY_DESC,description);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null, cv);
}

public long createEntry1(String id, String description){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_ROWID,"P01");
    cv.put(KEY_DESC,"Snow White");
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null, cv);
}


public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_DESC};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    String result =" ";
    
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iDescription = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESC);
    
 for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
    result =result + c.getString(iRow)+ "  " +c.getString(iDescription) +"  \n";
    }

    return result;
    
}
```

main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";
Button view;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    view =(Button) findViewById(R.id.viewSQL);
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
    
}



  //product qr code mode
public void scanQR(View v) {
    try {
        //start the scanning activity from the com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        
        
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        //on catch, show the download dialog
        showDialog(MainActivity.this, "No Scanner Found", "Download a scanner code activity?", "Yes", "No").show();
    }
}

//alert dialog for downloadDialog
private static AlertDialog showDialog(final Activity act, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, CharSequence buttonYes, CharSequence buttonNo) {
    AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
    downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
    downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
    downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:" + "com.google.zxing.client.android");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            try {
                act.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

            }
        }
    });
    downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        }
    });
    return downloadDialog.show();
}

//on ActivityResult method
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //get the extras that are returned from the intent
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Content:" + contents + " Format:" + format, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    
        case R.id.viewSQL:   
            
            Translator entry = new Translator(MainActivity.this);
            entry.open();
            entry.close();
            Intent i = new Intent("com.example.scanner.SQLVIEW");
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

SQLView.java

```
public class SQLView extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);
    TextView tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSQLint);
    Translator info = new Translator(this);
    info.open();
    String data = info.getData();
    info.close();
    tv.setText(data);
    

}
```

this is my error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

ComponentInfo{com.example.scanner/com.example.scanner.SQLView}: 

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: page_desc

(code 1):, while compiling: SELECT _id, page_desc FROM pageTable
```

What is my error?

Comment: Does creating the table produce an error? Can you share it please?

Comment: nope, when i debug the project it does not appear any error. When i run it in device,the error appear, when i click view button (it will show data in  database) it says there are no columns such page_desc

Comment: Possibly your device has an older version of the database file. Uninstall your app to get rid of it, and reinstall and run to create a new one.

Comment: It seems you altered the database. Then you should increase the value of `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION  = 1;` to a higher number.

Comment: @DerGolem i wanna ask opinion from you, it is about my project.Basically my project is  create application for book translation using qr code, the way it will work is when user scan qr code using this application that i put in each page, it will show the translation for that page(the translation will be write in database), the way i see how it work is in each qr code, i will put Unique ID in it, that will connect to Database. But i cant see how the coding to connect the qr code with database. Is this possible to do,

Comment: I think your life would be much easier if you put a link to a translated web page in every QR code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class Translator extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String LOGCAT = null;

public Translator(Context applicationcontext) {
    super(applicationcontext, "androidsqlite.db", null, 1);
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "Created Translator Database");
}

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_DESC = "page_desc";

private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "pageTable";

private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
            + " STRING PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_DESC + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}

public long createEntry(String id, String description) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_ROWID, id);
    cv.put(KEY_DESC, description);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public long createEntry1(String id, String description) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_ROWID, "P01");
    cv.put(KEY_DESC, "Snow White");
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_DESC };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    String result = " ";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iDescription = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESC);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + "  "
                + c.getString(iDescription) + "  \n";
    }

    return result;

}
}
```

Comment: @SmulianJulain thanks,its works well,can you please explain to me what you change, 
and can you see my coding to view data, what do i need to change.

Comment: I had a feeling you were calling the activity Translator but not the method DbHelper in the activity Translator. I don't know a lot about databases but that is what I thought. It could be as Der Golem stated. He did not get 17K points by accident.